# Oracle ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, user-defined-types, member-functions

I am trying to create a member function that returns the member names of expired members. My select query works outside of the member function and this member function compiles with no problems but when I call the function I get this error:

ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

I assume it is something simple but I have not been using Oracle for long so got a bit stuck with syntax. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Is there a particular reason for going down this object-oriented route, rather than just using the database relationally?

Comment: Why did you remove the code sample?  The question is utterly  meaningless without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this query can return more than one row you need to use a cursor and a cursor-for loop to iterate over results. However you cannot return more than one member name using a varchar; you could use a PL-SQL table.

Answer (score 0):

select m.forename into memberName
  from member_tab m
  where ADD_MONTHS(m.datejoined, 64) < SYSDATE;

looks like this query is returning more than 1 results ...

u can use a select count(*) or exception handling to address the exception and handle >1 results

Comment: Thanks for this, I have tried the count but I still get duplicated rows? Do you know how to get a count to only display one row?

Comment: u can use count to check if there are more than 1 rows not to fix it.
do you intend to return all such values or just 1 value from the function?